# Looking for feedback on my first project

Tags: sound-design, foley, music, practice

don't know if this is the right place to post but here it goes;

I've been working on a project where I took an animated short film, and replaced all of its original sound with my own sounds, foley and music. This is the first time I attempt such a thing and it would be really nice to hear some feedback from someone with a little more experience. I would really appreciate it. Here's the link:

Comment: Hi there, and welcome. If you have questions on how to create a particular sound or effect, or if you are having a problem, are on topic. This is a request for opinion, which is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds really good overall.  I wasn't really buying the footsteps much, they seemed to be mixed pretty present but with a couple missing r strange sync.  If they were lower you could get away with 1 or 2 missing but at he level they are at it can be distracting.  I think you have the correct sounds in the "germ" section but they could be fine tuned or mixed differently.  Right now the one with the most impact is the 1st time he looks at them and it should probably be when he sees the germs in himself I'd guess.  Maybe mix the first ones lower and the germs from his hand louder and have it noticeably start right on the cut, at the moment it seems like there is a lower intensity sound on the cut so it doesn't have quite the impact.  The puking and then the slap at the end could both be in their space a little more I feel and maybe the slap should be a little bigger or more slap like.  This is just what stuck out from watching it through once, very good overall.